# Using the Python Google Firestore client with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-firestore, cython, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to execute a Python script using PySpark. However, one library that is crucial to the job is [Google Cloud's Firestore API client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/firestore) `google-cloud-firestore`. I have data in a Firestore database that I need to access to run the code.

The problem is that it relies on a C implementation of GRPC and so it can't be zipped and passed to the `spark-submit` query along with the rest of the Python libraries I rely on.

I have read about baking the library into the Spark image or running it when the node starts but struggling to find how to do this within the PySpark framework.

If I execute the following line (`libs.zip` has all the dependencies including Firestore, `jobs.zip` has all the Python code for running the jobs which all work fine as long as it doesn't rely on accessing Firestore):

```
spark-submit --py-files jobs.zip,libs.zip main.py --job myjob
```

I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'
```

So, my question is how can I incorporate the `google-cloud-firestore` library into a PySpark framework, so that I can access data from Firestore?

EDIT: `libs.zip` contains all the downloaded Python libraries listed in `requirements.txt`, which includes `google-cloud-firestore`, `grpc` and `grpcio`. To illustrate:

[image: libs screenshot]

Comment: What exactly is inside of `libs.zip`? Does it contain the wheels for both `google-cloud-firestore` and `grpcio`?

Comment: @RichardBelleville I've amended the question to help answer your question